# Open a file from crystal report export to stream function

Tags: crystal-reports

How can i open a file directly from stream which is exported through crystal report export to stream function? I am using vs2010 and sap crystal report.

```
MemoryStream m = (MemoryStream)(PReport.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat));
FileStream f = new FileStream(purchaseCombo.SelectedItem.ToString(),FileMode.Create,System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
byte[] bytes = new byte[m.Length];
m.Read(bytes, 0, (int)m.Length);
f.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
f.Close();
m.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the file that you are exporting. Since Crystal Reports can export a number of different file types and each of them has a specific program that can handle it, you will need to search for the exact file type that you're interested. For example with a quick search on the internet, I found that a stream of an html file can be directly previewed inside a WebBrowser component (in a WPF app) by using the [NavigateToStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostream%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method. Maybe there are some 3rd party components that expose methods for directly opening files from memory.

Though, the easiest way would be to export a temporary file to disk instead of memory by using the [ExportToDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225954%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method and delete it after its usage, since many components read from paths rather than memory. Before exporting the file, you can use the [GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) method which creates and names a temporary file.